# Регулярное выражение PHP, проверка на слово

Tags: php

Есть теги offer и закрывающийся /offer, в некоторых из них есть слово, например "Hello", как проверить есть ли это слово в тегах и если это слово есть, удалить все в тегах

Пример исходного кода:

```
<offer id="81403" available="true">
<url>http://mysite.net/catalog/all/zapchasti_dlya_telefonov_i_noutbukov/zapchasti_dlya_telefonov/81403_shleyf_sonyericsson_t707_mezhplatnyy_original.html?r1=<?echo $strReferer1; ?>&amp;r2=<?echo $strReferer2; ?>&amp;from=market</url>
<seller_warranty>true</seller_warranty><store>true</store><delivery>true</delivery><vendor>Sony</vendor><price>273</price>
<currencyId>RUB</currencyId>
<categoryId>1813</categoryId>
<picture>http://mysite.net/upload/iblock/bb9/8544043f-b933-4b6f-af15-c05be9b291d1_bdfc495c-2226-11e6-9a8e-bcee7b5aca2b.jpeg</picture>
<name>Шлейф SonyEricsson T707 межплатный Оригинал Hello</name>
<description></description>
<sales_notes>Скидка 5% при оплате VISA, MasterCard</sales_notes>
</offer>
```

Answer (score 4):

если речь идет о html тегах, 
я бы советовал использовать http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/,
а именно

```
  <?php
    // подключаем класс simple_html_dom для разбора html
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
    // что ищем
    $findme = 'Hello';

    // Find all 
    foreach($html->find('offer') as $element) {
        $mystring = $element->innertext();
        $isFind = strpos($mystring, $findme);
        if ($isFind === false) {
            //не найдено
            //echo "Строка '$findme' не найдена в строке '$mystring1'";
        //if ($isFind === false)
        } else {
            //зачищаем
            $element->innertext('');
        }//else if ($isFind === false) 
    }//foreach($html->find('offer') as $element) 
    echo $html->innertext();
```

Comment: Call to undefined method simple_html_dom::innertext()
Проблема строка "echo $html->innertext();"

Comment: поторопился.. ну вместо $html->innertext(); нужно $res = $html->find('html'); $res = $res[0]; print_r($res->innertext()); // как-то так

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы так

```
$string = '<offer id="81403" available="true">
<url>http://mysite.net/catalog/all/zapchasti_dlya_telefonov_i_noutbukov/zapchasti_dlya_telefonov/81403_shleyf_sonyericsson_t707_mezhplatnyy_original.html?r1=<?echo $strReferer1; ?>&amp;r2=<?echo $strReferer2; ?>&amp;from=market</url>
<seller_warranty>true</seller_warranty><store>true</store><delivery>true</delivery><vendor>Sony</vendor><price>273</price>
<currencyId>RUB</currencyId>
<categoryId>1813</categoryId>
<picture>http://mysite.net/upload/iblock/bb9/8544043f-b933-4b6f-af15-c05be9b291d1_bdfc495c-2226-11e6-9a8e-bcee7b5aca2b.jpeg</picture>
<name>Шлейф SonyEricsson T707 межплатный Оригинал Hello</name>
<description></description>
<sales_notes>Скидка 5% при оплате VISA, MasterCard</sales_notes>
</offer>';

$need = 'Hello';
$pattern = '~<(\w+)>.*'. preg_quote($need, '~') .'.*</\1>~';
$string = preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($string); echo '</pre>';
/* Будет удалена вся строка вместе с тегом <name>:
<name>Шлейф SonyEricsson T707 межплатный Оригинал Hello</name>
*/
```

Comment: После первого тега offer идет id. И в offer есть другие теги

Comment: @Дима Кулик если вам нужно решение именно с использованием регулярных выражений, тогда приведите пример исходной строки в вашем вопросе (отредактируйте первый пост). Я позже буду за ПК, напишу пример (или кто-то напишет раньше)

Comment: Залил в pastebin: https://pastebin.com/dNX5guHk

Comment: @Дима Кулик ок, позже напишу пример и отредактирую свой ответ.

Comment: @Дима Кулик отредактировал свой ответ.