# JS/jQuery как лучше убрать теги с определенным словом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть тэги "< offer>" и "< /offer>". В некоторых из них есть слово "Hello". Как проверить есть ли это слово в тегах и если это слово есть, удалить все в тегах.

Пример кода со словом "Hello":

```html
<offer id="81403" available="true">
 <url>http://mysite.net/catalog/all/zapchasti_dlya_telefonov_i_noutbukov/zapchasti_dlya_telefonov/81403_shleyf_sonyericsson_t707_mezhplatnyy_original.html?r1=<?echo $strReferer1; ?>&amp;r2=<?echo $strReferer2; ?>&amp;from=market</url>
<seller_warranty>true</seller_warranty><store>true</store>
<delivery>true</delivery><vendor>Sony</vendor><price>273</price>
<currencyId>RUB</currencyId>
<categoryId>1813</categoryId>
<picture>http://mysite.net/upload/iblock/bb9/8544043f-b933-4b6f-af15-c05be9b291d1_bdfc495c-2226-11e6-9a8e-bcee7b5aca2b.jpeg</picture>
<name>Шлейф SonyEricsson T707 межплатный Оригинал Hello</name>
<description></description>
<sales_notes>Скидка 5% при оплате VISA, MasterCard</sales_notes>
</offer>
```

Comment: ты не определился с языком и инструментами https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/698848/191482 ?

Comment: Ага, регулярки для этого сложны

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('offer'))
  .filter(offer => offer.innerText.indexOf('Hello') != -1)
  .forEach(offer => offer.parentNode.removeChild(offer));
```

```html
<offer id="81403" available="true">
 <url>http://mysite.net/catalog/all/zapchasti_dlya_telefonov_i_noutbukov/zapchasti_dlya_telefonov/81403_shleyf_sonyericsson_t707_mezhplatnyy_original.html?r1=<?echo $strReferer1; ?>&amp;r2=<?echo $strReferer2; ?>&amp;from=market</url>
<seller_warranty>true</seller_warranty><store>true</store>
<delivery>true</delivery><vendor>Sony</vendor><price>273</price>
<currencyId>RUB</currencyId>
<categoryId>1813</categoryId>
<picture>http://mysite.net/upload/iblock/bb9/8544043f-b933-4b6f-af15-c05be9b291d1_bdfc495c-2226-11e6-9a8e-bcee7b5aca2b.jpeg</picture>
<name>Шлейф SonyEricsson T707 межплатный Оригинал Hello</name>
<description></description>
<sales_notes>Скидка 5% при оплате VISA, MasterCard</sales_notes>
</offer>

<offer id="4814032" available="true">
  Здесь нету Hello.
</offer>
<offer id="814032" available="true">
  Здесь точно нету.
</offer>
```

Comment: Вы очень сильно мне помогли, но только он чувств. к регистру, как исправить?

Comment: `offer.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf('hello')`